# Given some points in the Euclidean space, find a plane satisfying some restrictions

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis

In a 3-D Cartesian coordinates, suppose we are given $n$ points and their coordinate values in the form $(x,y,z)$. Obviously there are uncountable planes which divide those points into two groups, some on the one side of the plane and some on the other side.

For example, two points $(0,0,0)$ and $(2,0,0)$, the plane $x=1$ devides them into two groups. We define a set S to conclude those planes. For every such plane $P$, along with those $n$ points, we define $f(P)=max(d(x,P)+d(y,P))$, $d(x,P)$ being the distance between the point $x$ and the plane $P$. $x$ and $y$ belong to those given $n$ points but are from different groups.

The question is:

> How to find the function of the plane $W$ ($W$ is a member of $S$) such that $f(W)$ is the smallest compared with any other plane belonging to $S$? Is there any simple method?

Or

> Try to find the value of $f(W)$ in the condition above.

Advice of either of the questions would help!

Comment: Before you go any further, it' s *[plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(geometry))* not "plain." Also, linebreaks will help transform this monolithic block of text into a more attractive post to read.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I'm new here and in fact my mother tongue is not English. I will correct the mistakes.

Comment: I went ahead and made those changes, along with a few others. You can see what I did by clicking the edit timestamp. I hope you find the changes useful!

Comment: 没事儿！我知道英文的语法不算容易。这里的人肯定要帮忙。

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely clear whether you know in advance what the groups should be, or you want to let the algorithm decide this.

*Case 1*. You already know to which of two groups each of your $n$ points belongs; the plane is needed as a tool to classify other points that you may be given later. This is a *classification* problem of *supervised learning*, and  the appropriate tool is called a [support vector machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine).

*Case 2*. You don't know to which group your points belong; you need the plane to tell you this. Now we have a problem of *unsupervised learning*, which is going to be harder. You'll find some results and references in [Unsupervised SVMs:
On the Complexity of the Furthest Hyperplane Problem](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/proceedings/papers/v23/karnin12/karnin12.pdf). From the abstract:

> This paper introduces the Furthest Hyperplane Problem (FHP), which is an unsupervised counterpart of Support Vector Machines. Given a set of $n$ points in $\mathbb R^d$, the objective is to produce the hyperplane (passing through the origin) which maximizes the separation margin, that is, the minimal distance between the hyperplane and any input point.

Comment: In fact this problem comes from engineering. I am given 2500 points from a 'plane' and their coordinate values. I want to know whether this 'plane' is plane and how plane it is. So I define $f(P)$.

Comment: @PhilWang I see. Because you mentioned separating planes in your post, I decided that you are trying to separate the points. Instead you are just fitting a plane to them. This looks like a job for [total least squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares): the function $f$ should be the sum of squared distances to the plane.

Comment: Yes, total least squares is one of the methods. I have tried it. I have tried another method which is too complex to be employed in computer. Maybe there is no such 'simple' method here. I'll try. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My convex intuition says the following.

Let $A$ be the set consisting of $n$ given points. As I understood you, $f(P)$ should be equal to a width $w_r(A)$ of the set $A$  in the direction $r$ orthogonal to the plane $P$. So you have to find a minimal width of the set $A$. A width of a set in the given direction is a known notion, hence should be a information about it in the Internent. Moreover, my convex intuitions suggests that for each direction $r$ the width $w_r(A)$ is equal to a width $w_r(conv(A))$ of the convex hull $conv(A)$ of the set $A$. The set $conv(A)$ is a polytope and the minimal value of $w_r(conv(A))$ is achieved when $r$ is orthogonal to a face of the polytope $conv(A)$. In this case the minimal value of $f(P)$ can be found as follows.

For each triple $u,v,w$ of not-collinear points of $A$ consider a plane $P$, going through $u,v,w$.  The plane $P$ is determined by an equation $ax+by+cz+d=0$. Then the direction orthogonal  to the plane $P$ is $r=(a,b,c)$. For each point $t\in A$ the projection of the point
$t=(x,y,z)$ into direction $r$ is equal to $p_r(t)= ax+by+cz$. Put $p_r(A)=\{p_r(t):t\in A\}$. Then the width $f(P)=w_r(A)=\max p_r(A)-\min p_r(A)$. Then the required minimum of $f(P)$
should be equal to $\min\{w_r(A)\}$, where the set of all such $r$ is described above.

Comment: If $f(P)$ is the smallest, is it true that P goes through at least 3 points belonging to A?

Comment: I am not sure in it. But, at least, it seems that the smallest value of $f(P)$ is achieved on a plane going through at least 3 points of $A$. I see the situation as follows. Given a direction $r$, we sandwich :-) the set $A$ between two planes orthogonal to $r$. The distance $w_r(A)$ between 
these planes is equal to $f(P)$, where $P$ is a plane parallel to them. If no one of the two sandwich planes goes through $3$ points of $A$, then we can rotate these parallel planes (without the increasing of the distance between them) until we obtain 3 points of $A$ on one of the planes.

Comment: PS. And the the value of $f(W)$ which you are search should be equal to the minimal width of the convex hull of the set $A$.